# Cannot get elements from HTML with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the text from these elements from this HTML:

```
<div class="panel_descripcion">
        <span itemprop="description">
                <ul>
                    <li><span style="color: #666666;" class="texto7">Blah blah</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </span>
        <span itemprop="description">
                <ul>
                    <li><span style="color: #666666;" class="texto7">Blah blah</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </span>
        <span itemprop="description">
                <ul>
                    <li><span style="color: #666666;" class="texto7">Blah blah</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </span>
</div>
```

At the moment I have the following code, but I can't get it to work, the elements are found but the text retrieved is empty:

```
description_list = dr.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.panel_descripcion > span > span")
for description_elem in description_list:
    description = description_elem.text
```

I've made sure that no other `div` with class called `panel_description` in the rest of the HTML.

**EDIT**

This is code I've been using instead of the previous one, I've copied the wrong one, altough I didn't know it was incorrect!

```
description_list = dr.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.panel_descripcion > span")
    for description_elem in description_list:
        description = description_elem.find_element_by_css_selector("span").text
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: it's impossible that your selector div.panel_descripcion > span > span found elements from the given code! The selector should be div.panel_descripcion > span  span. So probably you have found a wrong elements.

Comment: instead of selenium use python requests api

Comment: @DenisKoreyba Sorry, I've copied the wrong one, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong selector, try with `div.panel_descripcion > span span`.

Difference between this and your code is that I removed `>` which selects child tag, and second span is not a child of first span.
Your tags go like this: div>span>ul>li>**span**, and your code was searching for div>span>**span** which doesn't exist.

See [here](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) for more details about cssSelectors.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I've copied the wrong one, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery selector like `$(".panel_descripcion span:eq(1) li")`
which will give text in second span --> li

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this if I'm not mistaken:

```
description_list = dr.find_element_by_css_selector('.panel_descripcion .texto7');
```

but it won't be flexible if the site you are trying to work on changes something and I think the css selector you are using to get the elements you wanted seems to be incorrect.

```
div.panel_descripcion > span > span
```

this would look for elements for this html format

```
<div class="panel_descripcion">
    <span itemprop="description">
        <span style="color: #666666;" class="texto7">Blah blah</span>
    </span>
    <span itemprop="description">
        <span style="color: #666666;" class="texto7">Blah blah</span>
    </span>
    <span itemprop="description">
        <span style="color: #666666;" class="texto7">Blah blah</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've copied the wrong one, I've edited my question.

Comment: great (thumbsup)